# How to load some page content after head.js finishes loading scripts

Tags: javascript, head.js

Am currently using head.js to defer loading of js files for my website. Am using colorbox in my project. The problem is that at times, the colorbox doesnt fully load (it opens the colorbox in a new page rather than in a dialog), but when i do several refreshes, it finally loads.

I guess it might be that the page content that is meant to open the colorbox dialog gets loaded even before colorbox js files are fully loaded by head.js. Is this the actual cause?

I would want to have colorbox display correctly each time without need for a refresh.

How do I keep the colorbox page code to execute only after head.js finishes loading all its dependent files?

thanks. nikk

Answer (score 0):

Put your colorbox html code in a div.

```
<div id="colorBoxDiv" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

In the last line of head.js, add this code:

```
$("#colorBoxDiv").html($("#colorBoxDiv").html()).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

head.js had a lot of different options how to do that. you can run callback function when needed files loaded, or use `test` feature api call. 
For example:

```
// queue scripts and fire a callback when loading is finished
head.load("file1.js", "file2.js", function() {
    // do something
 });

// same as above, but pass files in as an Array
head.load(["file1.js", "file2.js"], function() {
    // do something
});

// you can also give scripts a name (label)
head.load({ label1: "file1.js" }, { label2: "file2.js" }, function() {
    // do something
});

// same as above, but pass files in as an Array
head.load([{ label1: "file1.js" }, { label2: "file2.js" }], function() {
    // do something
});                   

// Labels are usually used in conjuntion with: head.ready()
head.ready("label1", function() {
    // do something
});

 // Actually if no label is supplied, internally the filename is used for the label
 head.ready("file1.js", function() {
    // do something
});
```

[More in documentation](http://headjs.com/site/api/v1.00.html#load)